# How do I merge React/Redux Starter kit with Hackathon-Starter Kit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, starter-kits

If I have already built my frontend using https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit - is there a way I can port this over to Hackathon Starter Kit  https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter?